# How to connect plugin 'html-minifier?

Tags: node.js, gulp, html-minifier

The following code does not work. I am trying to connect the ['html-minifier'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) plugin to 'gulp' via the ['vinyl-source-stream'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) plugin.

Why am I doing this? I read on [this page](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md) that you can connect the plugin 'browserify'. I wrote this code but it gives an error. How can I resolve it?

[image]

```
'use strict';
const { src, dest, series } = require('gulp')
const htmlMinify = require('html-minifier').minify;
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

const options = {
    includeAutoGeneratedTags: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    sortClassName: true,
    useShortDoctype: true
};
const result = htmlMinify('frontend/*.html', options)

function test() {
    return result.bundle()
        .pipe(source('frontend/**/*.html'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(dest('public'))
}

exports.build = series(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code and now the 'html-minifier' plugin can work directly in 'gulp'.
The **const options** variable is the 'html-minifier' plugin settings.
Then we create a **function gHtmlMinify** that can be run with the **gulp gHtmlMinify** command.
**return src(...)** is your html files path.
**.on('data', function(file) {...}** Each thread has a "data" event..
We hang the processing of the "data" event..
When the "data" event is called, the "file" object comes to us, which contains information: file name, file path, working directory and file contents.
The content of the file is represented as a read buffer **file.isBuffer()**.
**Buffer.from** The raw data is stored in instances of the **Buffer** class.
(**file.contents**.toString() This file content is BUFFER.
The **toString()** method returns a function that represents an object. Converts to a string.

**console.log ({** // Outputting the structure of what the file consists of.
**contents: file.contents,** // Content of the file BUFFER. The buffer is not a string!
**path: file.path,** // Path to the file.
**cwd: file.cwd,** // Current directory. "The directory where the gulp command was run".
**base: file.base,** // Value before asterisks i.e. app/
**relative: file.relative,** // Value after the asterisks i.e. filename.html
**dirname: file.dirname,** // File directory.
**basename: file.basename,** // File name.
**stem: file.stem,** // File name without extension.
**extname: file.extname** // File extension.
**})**

```
const { src, dest, series } = require('gulp');
const htmlMinify = require('html-minifier');

const options = {
    includeAutoGeneratedTags: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    sortClassName: true,
    useShortDoctype: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true
};

function gHtmlMinify() {
    return src('app/**/*.html')
        .on('data', function(file) {
            const buferFile = Buffer.from(htmlMinify.minify(file.contents.toString(), options))
            file.contents = buferFile;
            console.log(file);
            return;
        })
        .pipe(dest('build'))
}


exports.gHtmlMinify = series(gHtmlMinify)
```